# What is vba code to use filtered form results as recordset for a query

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

What is vba code to use filtered form results as recordset for a query?

I started first to see if I could create and then open a recordset…

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset 
Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone 
CurrentDb.OpenRecordset ("rst")
```

And got the Run-time error ‘3078’ The MS Access database engine cannot find the input table or query ‘rst’ I haven’t worked with recordsets before. Thank you

Comment: I started first to see if I could create and then open a recordset…

Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
CurrentDb.OpenRecordset ("rst")

And got the Run-time error ‘3078’ The MS Access database engine cannot find the input table or query ‘rst’

I haven’t worked with recordsets before.  Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `rst.OpenRecordset`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-openrecordset-method-dao

Comment: Thanks.  I replaced my last line of code with your suggestion and nothing happened.

Comment: Does anyone know the sequence of VBA code to establish a recordset that is a recordsetcone of the filtered form and open the recordset from a button on the form.  Thanks

Comment: It did nothing because all your code was doing was trying to open the recordset. "I started first to see if I could create and then open a recordset" - I showed you how to open it. If you want to set it as the recordsource for a form, then it would be something like `Form1.RecordSource = rst` - you never put variable names into quotes because then they are just literal strings.

Comment: oh ok.  I'll work with that.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually all you need is this

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset 
Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
```

The recordset clone is already opened, and already exists.

So, you don't need the OpenRecordset command at all. This out of the box "handy" RecordsetClone exists for all forms, and you don't even have to open it.

Now that recordset will have the filtered data. It really then becomes a question as to what you want to do with the data.

However, say you had a report based on the same table as the form, the form becomes filtered?

Well, you actually in that case don't need (nor want) a reocrdset, but to simply open up that form with the current/same forms filter.

You can thus do this:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptCustomers", , , Me.Filter
```

But, if you for some reason need/want to process a recordset based on the current filter? Then using RecordsetClone will work. And this is NOT to be confused with RecordSet.Clone (which also exits).

And as noted, it is already open and exists. So you only need this:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
```

Comment: And it is possible to interact with RecordsetClone without even setting a recordset object variable.

Comment: indeed. However, by casting to a DAO recordset, then you do get intel-sense - so it not all of a bad idea - but you are correct - and you can use findfirst and most operations against that reocrdset clone without even creating a record set var.